# When did J&B Scotch switch from corks to screw-tops?

Tags: scotch, distilleries

A friend of mine has come into possession of some rather old alcohol.  On one bottle of J&B Scotch, the label looks like [this one](https://www.masterofmalt.com/whiskies/j-and-b/j-and-b-rare-blended-scotch-whisky-1950s-whisky/) from 1958 and not any of their later ones, but my friend's bottle has a screw-top cap, not a cork.

When did J&B start using caps?  (There is no contact information on their web site to ask them directly.)

Comment: Try using the web address and just add info@ to contact them.  for example:  www.abcxyz.com  try info@abcxyz.com  or contact@

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From what I can find I'm not sure I can give an exact answer to the main question (when J&B started using screw caps) but I think I found something that matches your description, from 1972:

https://www.maxliquor.com/product-p/j-and-b-scotch-1972-quart.htm

[image: J&B Scotch Bottle, 1972]

As far as I can tell the label matches the picture on the page you linked and appears to have a screw-cap.

Also, on the website you linked to, there are example bottles from [the 60's](https://www.masterofmalt.com/whiskies/j-and-b/j-and-b-rare-75cl-1960s-whisky/) and [the 70's](https://www.masterofmalt.com/whiskies/j-and-b/j-and-b-1970s-whisky/).  Interestingly though, the 70's bottle has a different label than the one above from 1972.

Given all of this, I would assume the switch to screw caps happened in the late 60's or early 70's and that the bottle your friend obtained is likely from the same time period.

Comment: My friend reports that this looks exactly like her bottle (aside from hers missing the tag, but that can happen after 45 years).